# Amazon web services EMR: Install dependencies in Slave (Core/Task) nodes

Tags: python-2.7, boto3, amazon-emr

I am relatively new to AWS EMR, I install my python Library dependency from a shell script in the EMR.

But this installation does not affect Slave Nodes (core/Task), Dependencies get installed in the master node.

So now I am trying to write a script which installs dependencies on slave nodes.

Using boto3 Framework I am able to retrieve ID's.

```
response = emr_client.list_instances(
    ClusterId=cluster_id
)
instances =[]
for i in xrange(len(response["Instances"])):
    print response["Instances"][i]["Ec2InstanceId"]
    instances.append(response["Instances"][i]["Ec2InstanceId"])
```

Using the Instance-ids fire SSM send_command - In the normal ec2 instance this works but since this instance is in EM hence throws an error InvalidInstanceId

```
resp = ssm_client.send_command(
         InstanceIds=instances,
         DocumentName="setup.sh"
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

EMR provides the option called Bootstrap Actions which can be executed in all ec2 instances created for EMR before actual hadoop software is installed. I would suggest you to explore that option instead of manually running shell scripts one after the other.

EMR also provides the option of using custom AMI.  You can create Ec2 instance install your third party dependencies in it and create AMI for the same and use that AMI for creating EMR cluster.